# Build Error - Receiver type "ViewController" for instance messages is a forward declaration

Tags: iphone, ios5, compiler-errors

I am getting 2 errors when building, they are located in the AppDelegatem file

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

**line with two errors:**

```
self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
```

**Error1:**

```
Receiver type "ViewController" for instance messages is a forward declaration
```

**Error2:**

```
Receiver "ViewController" for class messages is a forward declaration
```

**line with Alert:**

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
```

**Alert:**

```
Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'UIViewController *' from 'ViewController*'
```

If needed you can find text files of
ViewControllerm
ViewControllerh
AppDelegatem
Here http://ninjabreakbot.com/stack/

Project is for iOS5, I am very new to this. Please let me know what is useful with questions such as this. Or if enough has been provided, your solutions!

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The error message: `instance messages is a forward declaration` typically means that you the compiler didn't know about the declaration of the class, i.e. you haven't included the proper header.

In your case write `#import <ViewController.h>` at the beginning of AppDelegate.m should address this compiler problem.

Comment: My AppDelegate.m file contains the line
    #import "ViewController.h"

There is a link to my files which you can view in my post, thank you very much for the help.

Comment: This answer really helped me with a category related problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Check `initWithNibName`. Is the nib file name `ViewController` or another name?

write `#import "ViewController.h"` and
 `@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *viewController;` in AppDelegate.h file

Write `@synthesize viewController ;` in AppDelegate.m file

.h file ::

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *viewController;

@end
```

.m file::

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize viewController ;



- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];

    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
@end
```

Comment: My .xib is called ViewController

Adding these lines does not resolve any errors
#import "ViewController.h" was not in my AppDelegate.h file, however the next line you mention is. Also adding the @synthesize viewController ; in AppDelegate.m file gives error (Illegal interface qualifier) Thank you for the help.

Comment: nib file name look like ViewController.xib in project navigator of X-code.

Comment: @PrasadG i got this error.. What i have to do.. Plz guide me  i get this in another view where i want to call one method

Comment: @Babul: How may i help to you?. Explain briefly to me.

Comment: @PrasadG i did like this in my app 
#ifdef __cplusplus
#import <OpenCV/opencv2/opencv.hpp> 
#import "OpenCVClientViewController.h"
#endif


i need to call the method in "OpenCVClientViewController" there it gives me the above posted error

Comment: @Babul: Why did you use #ifdef __cplusplus and #endif? Is it needed?

Comment: i dont know exactly.. Initially i get the error as shown in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12947971/when-ever-i-use-opencvclientviewcontroller-it-treats-as-mistake    later i did some modifications said by other friend then this error raised @PrasadG