# when ever i use OpenCVClientViewController it treats as mistake

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I integrated my project in to the below link 
http://aptogo.co.uk/2011/09/opencv-framework-for-ios/

There `OpenCVClientViewController.h, OpenCVClientViewController.mm and OpenCVClientAppDelegate.h, OpenCVClientAppDelegate.mm`

Here Problem Comes up when i do the following:
i need to call one method named `-(void)processFrame` in `OpenCVClientViewController.mm`
it gives the following error as the image shown below.
Even the changes what i did removed then also the errors are not clear.

Problem comes when ever i use `OpenCVClientViewController.mm` like below

```
OpenCVClientViewController *svc=[[OpenCVClientViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"OpenCVClientViewController" bundle:nil];

[svc processFrame];
```

[image]

If i remove the code what i placed above even though the errors are not removed
(Looks like a small error but i did not get where the mistake is)

Comment: Did you follow all guidelines described in there? I have downloaded the OpenCV client and built it without any problem. Maybe you are adding the source of OpenCVClient to your project without appropriate libraries? And if you have already added libraries, maybe you didn't put `#ifdef __cplusplus
#import <OpenCV/opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#endif` in your prefix header file? And remember, you have to import OpenCV header files before `#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#endif`.

Comment: i put this "#ifdef __cplusplus #import <OpenCV/opencv2/opencv.hpp> #endif" in prefix header file it giving an error @FahriAzimov

Comment: i did what u said  now i am getiing differnt error message it says "receiver type instance message forward declaration"    @Guntis Treulands

Comment: i did like this in my .m file
#ifdef __cplusplus
#import <OpenCV/opencv2/opencv.hpp> 
#endif

#ifdef __OBJC__ 
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#endif @Guntis Treulands